# dd decreased the size of ssd

Tags: partitioning, ssd, dd

My 32 Gb ssd was partitioned with 8 Gb and 29 Gb. I used dd to write ubuntu iso onto my pendrive but accidentally wrote it to my 8 gb partition of my ssd. Now gparted dosent show that 8 Gb partition.
How do i recover it?? 
the command was `dd if=path_to_iso of=/dev/sdb` where sdb is the ssd
Output of `sudo fdisk -l` is :

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes  
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors  
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes  
Disk identifier: 0xb367fbf3  

  ` Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT  
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.  `

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes  
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62533296 sectors  
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disk identifier: 0x01a1f343  

  ` Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  `
```

and output of `df -h` is :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sda7       303G  8.3G  280G   3% /  
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
udev            2.9G  4.0K  2.9G   1% /dev  
tmpfs           594M  1.2M  593M   1% /run  
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock  
none            2.9G  288K  2.9G   1% /run/shm  
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
```

output of `sudo parted -l` is :

```
Model: ATA ST500LT012-9WS14 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B  
Partition Table: gpt  

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags  
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot  
 2      525MB   567MB   41.9MB  fat32           Basic data partition          hidden  
 3      567MB   701MB   134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres  
 4      701MB   1215MB  514MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag  
 5      1215MB  153GB   152GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata  
 7      153GB   484GB   331GB   ext4  
 8      484GB   489GB   5243MB  linux-swap(v1)  
 6      489GB   500GB   11.0GB  ntfs            Microsoft recovery partition  hidden, diag  


Model: ATA LITEONIT LMS-32L (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: msdos  

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags
```

it was by mistake that I forgot to put sdb1

`sudo parted /dev/sdb print free` gives :

```
Model: ATA LITEONIT LMS-32L (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: msdos  

Number  Start   End     Size    Type  File system  Flags  
        32.3kB  32.0GB  32.0GB        Free Space
```

gparted shoows 29 gb as unallocated

Comment: Please show us the `dd` command you used and also the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `df -h`.

Comment: @terdon i have used dd if=path_to_iso of=/dev/sdb

Comment: Please also include the output of the two commands I asked for. You did not specify a partition number (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`) and that is probably the problem. The `fdisk -l` output should clarify things.

Comment: @terdon updated it

Comment: OK, you're using a GPT partitioning scheme. In that case, we need the output of `sudo parted -l`, not `fdisk`, sorry. In any case, it looks like your `dd` command has deleted your partitions (which is what it should do since you copied to the disk and not to a partition like `sdb1`).

Comment: @terdon by mistake i forgot to put sdb1

Answer (score 1):

OK, your `dd` command has overwritten your partition table. WHen you specify a dev name with no number (e.g. `/dev/sdb`) that refers to the **entire** disk, not to a particular partition. So, when you ran `dd if=path_to_iso of=/dev/sdb`, you copied the image directly to the disk and destroyed your GPT Header files.

What you *wanted* to run was:

```
dd if=path_to_iso of=/dev/sdb2
```

You might be able to recover from this but there are no guarantees. If you're lucky, you will have a backup GPT table stored. If so, `gdisk` might be able to save you. Try

```
 gdisk /dev/sdb
```

You should see lines like

```
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged
****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
```

The details will be different but some kind of similar message should be there. If you're lucky, `gdisk` will automatically fix everything. If not, see [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) for more information.

Comment: Nice. I learn something new every day.